# SQL BigQuery: For the current month, count number of distinct CustomerIDs in the previous 3 month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The following is the table with distinct CustomerID and Trunc_Date(Date,MONTH) called Date.

| DATE | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 111 |
| 2021-01-01 | 112 |
| 2021-02-01 | 111 |
| 2021-03-01 | 113 |
| 2021-03-01 | 115 |
| 2021-04-01 | 119 |

For a given month M, I want to get the count of distinct CustomerIDs of the three previous months combined. Eg. for the month of July (7), I want to get the distinct count of CustomerIDs from the month of April (4), May (5) and until June (6). I do not want the customer in July (7) to be included for the record for July.

So the output will be like:

| DATE | CustomerID Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 535 |
| 2021-02-01 | 657 |
| 2021-03-01 | 777 |
| 2021-04-01 | 436 |
| 2021-05-01 | 879 |
| 2021-06-01 | 691 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this problem by creating a record for each month in the three following months and then aggregating:

```
select date_add(date, interval n month) as month,
       count(distinct customerid)
from t cross join
     unnest(generate_array(1, 3, 1)) n
group by month;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below

```
select distinct date, 
  ( select count(distinct id)
    from t.prev_3_month_customers id
  ) customerid_count
from (
  select *, 
    array_agg(customerid) over(order by pos range between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) prev_3_month_customers,
  from (
    select *, date_diff(date, '2000-01-01', month) pos
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
) t
```

If applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate your help! Sadly, BigQuery ran out of memory running this since we have lots of data. I will see if I can modify some things from your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: i see. so you should unaccept this answer then so others see you still need help. I will also look further - i have another option which should work for cases like yours :o)

Comment: @user16438416 - see my new answer - it should address any memory related issues which usually take place for really big data with high cardinality. Also, it should run much faster than when count(distinct) is used - obviously for the price of giving approximate counts

Answer (score 1):

> BigQuery ran out of memory running this since we have lots of data

In cases like this - the most scalable and performant approach is to use [HyperLogLog++ functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions) as in example below

```
select distinct date, 
  ( select hll_count.merge(sketch)
    from t.prev_3_month_sketches sketch
  ) customerid_count
from (
  select *, 
    array_agg(customers_hhl) over(order by pos range between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) prev_3_month_sketches,
  from (
    select date_diff(date, '2000-01-01', month) pos, 
      min(date) date,
      hll_count.init(customerid) customers_hhl
    from `project.dataset.table`
    group by pos
  )
) t
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: *HLL++ functions are approximate aggregate functions. Approximate aggregation typically requires less memory than exact aggregation functions, like COUNT(DISTINCT), but also introduces statistical uncertainty. This makes HLL++ functions appropriate for large data streams for which linear memory usage is impractical, as well as for data that is already approximate.*